# child component does not rerender with shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle

My child component changes its state when its prop is changed. I want to re-render child component ImageSlide so call different string when state changes. The className is well changed and console shows the changed values well. But it does not rerender view.

I tried shouldComponentUpdate, but it did not work.
How can I re-render ImageSlide?

```
let languages = {
    en: require('textEnglish'),
    kr: require('textKorean')
}

class ImageSlide extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
        lang: this.props.lang,
        url: this.props.url
    }
}

languageSelect=()=> {
    if (this.state.lang === 'kr') {
        return 'kr';
    } else {
        return 'en';
    }   
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
    if (nextProps.lang !== prevState.lang |
        nextProps.url !== prevState.url )
    {
        return  {lang : nextProps.lang, url: nextProps.url} ;
    }
}


shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    return true;
 //I tried also:
 // if (nextProps.url !== this.state.url |
 // nextProps.lang !== this.state.lang)
 //     return true;
}

render() {
    const Text=languages[this.languageSelect()];
    return (    
        <div className="test-transition">
            {console.log(this.state.lang)}
            {console.log(this.state.url)}
            {console.log(Text["p1_3_"+String(this.state.url)])}
            <div className={`pic${this.state.url}`}>
                {Text["p1_3_"+String(this.state.url)]}              
            </div>
        </div>      
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check if the new props is changes or not using any of the lifecycle event like `componentDidUpdate` or `shouldComponentUpdate` or you can also try `componentWillReceiveProps` (not recommended since its deprecated)

```
componentDidUpdate()
    {
    /*Check for prev props condition*/
    this.forceUpdate(); /*this method renders the component*/
    }
```